# big queryで日付を指定して取り出す方法

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

googleのbig queryを使ってある日付から日付までの行を取り出したいのですが、以下のコードを実行すると１件も対象コードになりません。どこを改善すればよいのでしょうか。
対象テーブルはデフォルトで存在するものです。対象テーブルの画像を添付しました。

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

```
SELECT
　*
FROM `nyc-tlc.green.trips_201*`
WHERE
　 _TABLE_SUFFIX BETWEEN FORMAT_DATE('%Y%m%d', "2014-01-01") AND　FORMAT_DATE('%Y%m%d', "2015-03-04")
```

Comment: コード装飾に必要な行頭スペースが全角になっていました。手動でスペースを入れずとも、コード部分を範囲選択してエディタ上部の `{}` を押すとコードが装飾できますので、次からお試しください。

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT *
FROM
nyc-tlc.green.trips_201* 
WHERE
pickup_datatime >= timestamp('YYYY-MM-DD')
AND pickup_datatime < timestamp('YYYY-MM-DD')
```

pickup_datatime の日時を選択

```
SELECT *
FROM
nyc-tlc.green.trips_201* 
WHERE
DATE_ADD(pickup_datatime, 9, "HOUR") >= timestamp('YYYY-MM-DD')
AND DATE_ADD(pickup_datatime, 9, "HOUR") < timestamp('YYYY-MM-DD')
```

日本時間で取得 ↑